# <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters> and xmlns:local

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

The question is quite simple:

There is a namespace `xmlns:local= "clr-namespace:Notify"`.

There is a Class "Notify". The class is located right in the solution

There is a XAML-code:

```
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type Type="local:Notify"/>
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```

In this form everything works as it should be. I want to move the Notify Сlass to another class, such as the MainClass, so make Notify a subclass of MainClass. What do I need to change in the code to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to [use + for nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371083/1997232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlns:local= "clr-namespace:Notify"` to `xmlns:local= "clr-namespace:MainClass+Notify"`

and

```
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type Type="local:MainClass+Notify"/>
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```

Comment: You miss *"make Notify a subclass of MainClass"*.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but yes, I need to refer somehow to Notify class.