# In a XAML ResourceDictionary, how create a reference to an IValueConverter that is a nested class?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, inner-classes, resourcedictionary

Given a class that implements `IValueConverter`:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ...;
    }

    // Never called.
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

It is straightforward to create a keyed ResourceDictionary entry, *if* that is not a nested class:

```
<ContentView
    ...
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Converters" 
    x:Class "MyNamespace.MyView">
    
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
            ...
```

But suppose it is a *nested class*:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    ...
```

A nested class can't be referred to as an element name (would not be valid XML nor XAML):

```
// Won't compile.
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:OuterClass.MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
        ...
```

OR

```
        <converters:OuterClass+MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
        ...
```

HOWEVER, if there is an equivalent XAML that moves the class name to a property value, then it can be done, as described in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006566/199364):

```
<??? SomeProperty="converters:OuterClass+MyConverter" x:Key="myConverter" />
```

OR MAYBE ONE OF THESE, per [x:Type Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xtype-markup-extension):

```
<x:Type TypeName="converters:OuterClass+MyConverter" x:Key="myConverter" />
<x:Type TypeName="converters:OuterClass.MyConverter" x:Key="myConverter" />
<??? SomeProperty="{x:Type converters:OuterClass+MyConverter}" x:Key="myConverter" />
```

I've tried all of these, plus other variations (e.g. replace `???` with `IValueConverter`, or `object`).
So far I've always gotten either build-time problem:

```
Type '...' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.
```

OR at runtime when open the view:

```
System.RuntimeType doesn't implement interface Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter
... SIGABRT
```

Q: Is there a way to specify an `IValueConverter` resource, when the type is a nested class?

NOTE:

- I've verified that the class works if it is *not* nested. [That is the solution I am using now. But I would prefer to nest the classes within the code behind class, because this is *only* used on this view.]

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT - take any sample that includes an `IValueConverter`. For example, [Value Converters doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) links to source code; browse to  [IntToBoolConverter](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/DataBindingDemos/Converters/IntToBoolConverter.cs). Change `public class IntToBoolConverter : IValueConverter { ... }` to `public class OuterClass { public class IntToBoolConverter : IValueConverter { ... } }`. Try to use it from XAML.

Comment: If you just want to keep it together for logical reasons you can create a flat outer class inside the class.

Comment: How do you refer to it? If my class is named `MyView`, and I put inside it `public class MyConverter : IValueConverter`, then I haven't found any way to refer to `MyConverter` from `MyView.xaml`. If do `<MyConverter>`, get error `"MyConverter was not found"`. Using an `xmlns:myNamespace=...` declaration line doesn't help, because that only makes it possible to refer to classes directly in that namespace. `<myNamespace:MyConverter>` only works if MyConverter is directly in the namespace, not inside `MyView`. I haven't found any way in a xaml element name to refer to `MyView.MyConverter` class.

Comment: ... Therefore, I am forced to to do `namespace MyNameSpace { class MyConverter { ... } }`, even though I'd rather not have `MyConverter` visible to any class except `MyView`. Its a minor point; I am just curious whether there is any way to make a xaml element or resourcedictionary entry of type `namespace MyNameSpace { class MyView { class MyConverter ... } } }`. So far, I haven't found any.