# WPF ContextMenu to access row selected

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a WPF application that has a `ListView` with a `GridView` in it.  It has a `ContextMenu` when you right-click on the items in the grid.  I was wondering how I can access the row that is selected from the `ContextMenu` and access that programatically.  My goal is to delete that row of data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work using [WPF command bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)...

```xml
    <ListView>
        <!-- .... -->
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Remove Item" Command="{Binding RemoveItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" Icon="{StaticResource deleteIcon}"/>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    </ListView>
```

To create *custom command bindings*, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601415/175679).