# Create ShortcutKey to call a method

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I wish I could define any sort of shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Tab</kbd> to call a method. I tried to use `CommandBinding` and `KeyBinding` without any success. If I ain't wrong, the only way would use the `CanExecute` or `Executed` of `CommandBinding` to do that, but I didn't know how to associate that with any custom shortcut that I wanted, and it's necessary to define the `Command` with, for example, `ApplicationCommands.Open`.

It would be perfect if I could simply define the shortcuts like `Key="B"` and `Modifiers="Control"` with the command `Command="SomeEventHandlerHere"`, but it isn't going that simple, unfortunately.

**EDIT**

I've tried this so far (it looks so wrong even to me):

```
CommandBinding cb = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.NotACommand, MyMethod);
KeyGesture kg = new KeyGesture(Key.B, ModifierKeys.Control);
KeyBinding kb = new KeyBinding(ApplicationCommands.NotACommand, kg);
this.InputBindings.Add(kb);

private void MyMethod(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Its almost that simple.  Why dont you post the code that you've created so far and we'll see how close you really are.

Comment: It looks like your question is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf

Comment: It really seems to be the same question. But could you help me about this line?: `Command="{x:Static local:MyWindow.MyCommand}`.

I'm getting an error: `The namespace prefix "local" is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found what I was looking for.

In order to create my own command (instead of using pre-existing ones like "Open", "Help", "Save", etc), I need to create a new RoutedUICommand. Next, we create a CommandBinding to associating the Command with the methods.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="MyCustomCommand"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource MyCustomCommand}" Executed="CommandExecutedMethod" CanExecute="CommandCanExecuteMethod"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

In the code behind we have:

```
private void CommandCanExecuteMethod(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void CommandExecutedMethod(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Command executed");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Now I can do what I was looking for:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="G" Modifiers="Control" Command="{StaticResource MyCustomCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

With the above, if the window is focused, when we press Ctrl + G, the method `CommandExecutedMethod` is called.

We also can use the command like this:

```
<Button Content="Click me" Command="{StaticResource MyCustomCommand}" />
```

Fonts:
[Tech.Pro](http://tech.pro/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands)
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601393/how-do-i-add-a-custom-routed-command-in-wpf)