# WPF, ApplicationCommands, RoutedUICommand and CommandBindings

Tags: wpf, menuitem

Hi I am having trouble with WPF creating a RoutedUICommand that works similar to an ApplicationCommand. Ideally I want to have a single 'Duplicate' MenuItem that works with two different UserControls. Whether or not the MenuItem is active will depend on which UserControl is selected and if the UserControl contains a selected object (the same way cut, copy and past work on different textboxes, etc).

As per this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601393/how-do-i-add-a-custom-routed-command-in-wpf), question I have created the static class below:

```
namespace App.Classes
{
    public static class myCommands
    {
        private static readonly RoutedUICommand _duplicateCmd = new RoutedUICommand("Duplicate", "Duplicate", typeof(myCommands));

        public static RoutedUICommand Duplicate
        {
            get { return _duplicateCmd; }
        }
    }
}
```

In the main Window's XAML file I have added a reference to the class's namespace and a KeyBinding to the command.

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.App.Views.Windows.wndMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:App.Classes">

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="D" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding classes:myCommands.Duplicate}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

In the MenuItem I have added a Command binding to the 'Duplicate' command

```
<MenuItem Name="mnCopy" Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" />      
<MenuItem Name="mnDuplicate" Header="Duplicate" Command="{Binding classes:myCommands.Duplicate}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+D"/>
```

And finally in each of my UserControls I have added CommandBindings to the 'Duplicate' and other ApplicationCommands.

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings> 
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" Executed="CommandBinding_Copy" CanExecute="CommandBindingCanExecute_Copy" />
    <CommandBinding Command="classes:myCommands.Duplicate" Executed="CommandBinding_DuplicateControls" CanExecute="CommandBindingCanExecute_DuplicateControls" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

The code-behind for my Executed and CanExecute for each of the UserControls is

```
/// <summary>                                                                                                   
///                                                                                                             
/// </summary>                                                                                                  
public void CommandBinding_Copy(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.Copy();
}

/// <summary>                                                                                                   
///                                                                                                             
/// </summary>                                                                                                  
public void CommandBinding_Duplicate(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.Duplicate();
}

/// <summary>                                                                                                   
///                                                                                                             
/// </summary>                                                                                                  
public void CommandBindingCanExecute_Copy(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.CanExecute_Copy();
}

/// <summary>                                                                                                   
///                                                                                                             
/// </summary>                                                                                                  
public void CommandBindingCanExecute_Duplicate(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.CanExecute_Duplicate();
}
```

This works perfectly for my ApplicationCommands and the appropriate **Executed** and **CanExecute** get called depending upon which UserControl is selected. But I can't get it to work with my 'Duplicate' RoutedUICommand. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or am missing? Will be grateful for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding to a static property via `Path` and that won't work. Change `Binding` to `x:Static` and should work

```
<MenuItem Name="mnCopy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />      
<MenuItem Name="mnDuplicate" Command="{x:Static classes:myCommands.Duplicate}"/>
```

On a side note `RoutedUICommand` has overloaded constructor that accepts `InputGestureCollection` where you can bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when you command is created.

```
private static readonly RoutedUICommand _duplicateCmd = 
    new RoutedUICommand(
           "Duplicate", 
           "Duplicate", 
           typeof(myCommands), 
           new InputGestureCollection(new InputGesture[] { new KeyGesture(Key.D, ModifierKeys.Control) }));
```

advantage is that you won't have to specify `InputGestureText`, as you don't have to `ApplicationCommands.Copy`, and because you use `RoutedUICommand` you also don't need to specify `Header`. If you do that **both `InputGestureText` and `Header` will be taken by default from your `RoutedUICommand`** and all you actually need to specify against `MenuItem` is a `Command`

Comment: Hi dkozl, I changed Binding to x:static as you suggested and it works brilliantly. I also, added in the other stuff about the InputGesture and that works great too. Thanks loads and loads.