# Get parameter passed in navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters, navigation, modern-ui

I'm using modernUI with WPF in my desktop application. I use the code below to navigate to my usercontrol (acts like a page).

```
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("/Pages/MyPage.xaml?Id=" + id, this);
```

The navigation works well but the problem is that I don't know how I can get the Id passed as parameter. How can I fetch a parameter from MyPage.xaml?

Answer (score 2):

I think that implementing the `IContent` interface can be a solution. If you want to get the Id, you should use `#` instead of `?`.

```
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("/Pages/MyPage.xaml#" + id, this);
```

In this case MyPage.xaml.cs can be the following:

```
public void OnFragmentNavigation(FragmentNavigationEventArgs e)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Fragment))
   {
      // do what you want
      // e.Fragment will be the id
   }
}
```

More information on [GitHub](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Handle-navigation-events).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. What if I want to pass an object as a parameter (DataTable, enum item, whatever...))

Comment: I think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601393/how-do-i-add-a-custom-routed-command-in-wpf) could help if that is the case.

Comment: @gaborhodi Hello, i have the exact same problem and i created a class called IContent like so: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Handle-navigation-events.
i also added the implementations and the code never reaches this point. can you help me?

Comment: I suggest you @Kunal to create a new question and provide code snippets.