# Type reference cannot find type named Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

I want to have custom `Command`s to respond to in my application.
So I was following the instructions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601415/1045510), and created a static class for my commands:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public static class Commands {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Create = new RoutedUICommand(
            "Create Thing", nameof(Create),
            typeof(MyControl)
        );
    }
}
```

I then tried using it on my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyControl"

             ...boilerplate...

             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:Commands.Create"
                        CanExecute="CanCreateThing"
                        Executed="CreateThing"/>
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>

    ...the control's contents...
</UserControl>
```

The method `CanCreateThing` always sets `CanExecute` to true. `CreateThing` currently does nothing.

I get this error on the usage of `MyControl` in the window XAML:

```
Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly}Commands'.
```

And this one in the `Command="..."` attribute in the binding.

```
Invalid value for property 'Command': 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue'
```

## UPDATE

[Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465101/type-reference-cannot-find-type-named-commands#comment56672358_34465101) got rid of the errors, however, the menu items with those commands are still grayed out. Relevant code:

```
<TreeView ...>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Create}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    ...
</TreeView>
```

`MyControl.xaml.cs`

```
//...
private void CanCreateThing(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
//...
```

Comment: Try `Command="{x:static local:Commands.Create}"` in the binding.

Comment: @Mathew Please see edit.

Comment: Double check that DeleteItem command's CanExecute actually points to  CanCreateThing method.

Comment: @E-Bat Woops the `DeleteItem`is another command, I meant to write `Create`. And its `CanExecute` is correctly bound, as you can see above. Fixed question.

Answer (score 0):

With [Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219933/mathew)'s help, a fix was found:

First, I had to replace all instances of `local:Commands.Create` with `{x:Static local:Commands.Create}`. However, the menu items would still be gray.

So in each menu item, I added a `CommandTarget` referencing the ancestor `ContextMenu`:

```
<MenuItem Command="{x:Static local:Commands.CreateTrigger}"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
```

And that made the menu items clickable.